# Python Keyerror even when key exists

Tags: python, function, key

I defined `detect_groups_tile_num` function and then call it using `data.detect_groups_tile_num()['tile_num'][0]`. My code raised `KeyError: 0` error.

```
def detect_groups_tile_num(self, return_groups=True, return_tile_num=True, return_tile_num_pergroup=True):
        """
        Detect the measurement groups and the tile_num range spanned by these measurements.
        :param return_groups: bool, whether to return the unique groups names.
        :param return_tile_num: bool, whether to return the global tile_num range.
        :param return_tile_num_pergroup: bool, whether to return the tile_num range per group.
        :return: dict, with keys groups, tile_num, tile_num_pergroup.
        """
        if return_tile_num_pergroup and not return_tile_num:
            return_tile_num = True
            warnings.warn('"return_tile_num" is False but "return_tile_num_pergroup" is True. "return_tile_num" will be set to True.')
        out = {}
        colnames = list(self.dataset.columns.values)
        colnames.remove(self.col_id)
        colnames.remove(self.col_class)
        groups = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys([i.split('_')[0] for i in colnames]))
        if return_groups:
            out['groups'] = groups
        if return_tile_num:
            tile_num = [int(i.split('_')[1]) for i in colnames]
            out['tile_num'] = [min(tile_num), max(tile_num)]
            if return_tile_num_pergroup:
                out['tile_num'] = {}
                for group in groups:
                    group_columns = [i for i in colnames if search('^{0}_'.format(group), i)]
                    group_tile_num = [int(i.split('_')[1]) for i in group_columns]
                    out['tile_num'][group] = [min(group_tile_num), max(group_tile_num)]
        return out

data_file = '../sample_data/sample_data.zip'

meas_var = None
start_tile_num = None
end_tile_num = None

# Update default for the data
meas_var = data.detect_groups_tile_num()['groups'] if meas_var is None else meas_var
start_tile_num = data.detect_groups_tile_num()['tile_num'][0] if start_tile_num is None else start_tile_num
end_tile_num = data.detect_groups_tile_num()['tile_num'][1] if end_tile_num is None else end_tile_num


print(data.detect_groups_tile_num()['tile_num'])
{'col': [0, 75]}
```

Traceback:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_20041/2710866643.py in <module>
>       4 # Update default for the data
>       5 meas_var = data.detect_groups_tile_num()['groups'] if meas_var is None else meas_var
> ----> 6 start_tile_num = data.detect_groups_tile_num()['tile_num'][0] if start_tile_num is None else start_tile_num
>       7 end_tile_num = data.detect_groups_tile_num()['tile_num'][1] if end_tile_num is None else end_tile_num
>       8 
> 
> KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Could you please print the `data.detect_groups_tile_num()['tile_num']` data and add that in your question?

Comment: Yes its already at the bottom. The output is `{'col': [0, 75]}`

Comment: which data you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

As the value of `data.detect_groups_tile_num()['tile_num']` is `{'col': [0, 75]}`, which is a `dict`. So if you want to access the data then you have to use the `dict` key.

**You can try this:**

```
data_dict = {'col': [0, 75]}

# full list of `col`
print(data_dict.get('col'))

# first value of `col`
print(data_dict.get('col')[0])

# last value of `col`
print(data_dict.get('col')[len(data_dict.get('col')) - 1])

# iterate through full list

for val in data_dict.get('col'):
    print(val)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 75]
0
75
0
75
```